# Uniform boundedness of series over square lattice

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

So, I have a square integer lattice, that is $p\in 2\pi\mathbb Z^2\setminus\{0\}$, and some positive real number $z\in\mathbb R^{>0}$ and the series
$$
\sum_{p\in 2\pi\mathbb Z^2\setminus\{0\},|p|\leq|z|^{-1}} \frac 1 {|p|^2}.
$$
This means the summation includes all lattice points $p$ that are inside the circle with radius $\frac 1 {|z|}.$

For my bigger proof to work, I need this series to converge uniformly (in regards to $z$ in a small neighborhood of $0$). Unfortunately, I don't really know how to tacle this problem. The only thoughts that I have had so far, have led me to believe that this series does **not** converge.

Comment: Are you sure it's not $\frac{1}{|p|^3}$? because it seems like this will diverge like the harmonic series.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Yes, I'm sure the exponent is $2$.

Comment: ok, then in that case if you let $z\to 0$, then the series will diverge, because for each $n\in\Bbb{N}$, the "nth stage of the lattice" has $8n$ points, and each point $p$ on the $n^{th}$ stage has absolute value $|p|\leq \sqrt{(2\pi n)^2+(2\pi n)^2}=\sqrt{8}\pi n$ (pythagoras... this is the distance of the point $2\pi n(1+i)$ from the origin). So, the series is essentially like $\sum\frac{1}{|p|^2}\geq \sum_n\frac{8n}{\left(\sqrt{8}\pi n\right)^2} = \sum_{n}\frac{1}{\pi^2n}$; and we know the harmonic series diverges.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your thoughts. It helps a lot!